# Socket ReceiveAsync merging packets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I intend to receive packets of data over a socket but since they are sent from the sender with a high frequency a number of them get packed into a single `byte` array. `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Buffer` then holds multiple packets, even though they were sent separately (verified using `wireshark`).

I have already tried to queue the incoming packets and asynchronously work them off, but still I get the same result.

What could be reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how TCP works. TCP connection is a *bi-directional stream of bytes*, and you have to treat it as such. Single send from one end might result in multiple reads on the receiving side, and vice versa, multiple sends might end up in a single read, and application message boundaries are not preserved by the transport.

You have to buffer the input until you know you have a complete application message. Common approaches are:

- fixed length messages,
- pre-pending length in front of the message,
- delimiting the stream with special "end-of-message" separator.

Comment: Exactly this, TCP is a stream protocol (stream of bytes - not packets - used by app). UDP is a datagram protocol (discrete packets)

Comment: The protocol i use is using Newline endings as delimiter. But also, some messages have newlines in their data - how am i supposed to difference between them?

Comment: Hmm, try some unprintable character, like `\001` (FIX field separator) or something else that is *not* in your data, to delimit messages.

Comment: I did not make the protocol myself. I have to react to it :/

Comment: A protocol used over a stream protocol, such as TCP *requires* some way to uniquely identify the message limits. Either through a unique character/sequence or through a length field in the message header. If none of them exists, the protocol is flawed and cannot be received reliably.

Comment: Most probably then not you need to *parse* the bytes as they come in - extract tokens, buffer if no token yet and wait, look at your state, decide what to do next. It's not trivial, but that's the only way to deal with ugly babies like XML.

Answer (score -3):

I might be mistaking, but isn't this the Naggle algorithm kicking in?
Your sockets should have a flag that disables this.

Comment: No, it's not. TCP is a stream. Expect to receive anywhere between 1 byte and minimum of the size of the supplied buffer and the number of bytes outstanding with every read. It doesn't matter if the data was sent with one or many send calls. Disabling nagle will NOT help; though it may appear to help. (-1)