# Not able to receive or send entire packet in socket programming using C

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, network-programming

I've been trying to send a packet from a client to a server via sockets. With the help of some of the tips I have made quite bit of progress in my code. However, the server only receives eight bytes from the client and prints them on the console whereas at my client side, It seems that it has sent everything.

Now I am not sure whether the problem is at the sending side or the receiving side. My hunch is that something is wrong at my client side. Could someone please help in verifying my assumption?

Client code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    data_struct client_data;
    struct packet
    { 
        long int srcID;
        long int destID;
        int pver;
        int profiles;
        int length;
        long int data;
    };


    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]); //Convert ASCII to integer
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // socket file descriptor

    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR DETECTED !!! Problem in opening socket\n");

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR DETECTED !!!, no such server found \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); //clear the memory for server address

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;    
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
        (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
        server->h_length);

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    printf("Client 1 trying to connect with server host %s on port %d\n", argv[1], portno); 


    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR in connection");

    printf("SUCCESS !!! Connection established \n");

    char buffer[256];
    struct packet *pkt = (struct packet *) buffer;
    char *payload = buffer + sizeof(struct packet);
    long double packet_size;



    printf("Started Creating packet\n");
    pkt->srcID = 01;
    pkt->destID = 02;
    pkt->pver = 03;
    pkt->profiles = 01;
    pkt->length = 16;
    pkt->data = 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8;
    {
        if (send(sockfd,pkt,sizeof(packet_size),0) <0)
            printf ("error\n");
        else
            printf ("packet send done");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Server code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    char wish;

    long int SrcID;
    long int DestID;
    int Pver;
    int Profiles;
    long int Data;
    int Length;
    char bytes_to_receive;
    int received_bytes;
    struct packet
    { 
        long int srcID;
        long int destID;
        int pver;
        int profiles;
        int length;
        long int data;
    };

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: %s port_number1",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR DETECTED !!! Problem in opening socket");

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR DETECTED !!! There was a problem in binding");

    listen(sockfd, 10);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    printf("Server listening on port number %d...\n", serv_addr.sin_port); 
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

    if (newsockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR DETECTED !!! the connection request was not accepted");

    char buffer[256];
    struct packet *pkt = (struct packet *) buffer;
    char *payload = buffer + sizeof(struct packet);
    long double packet_size;

    bytes_to_receive = sizeof(packet_size);
    received_bytes = 0;
    int rc =0;


    while ((rc = recv(newsockfd,pkt,sizeof(packet_size),0)) > 0)
    {
        received_bytes+=rc;
        SrcID = pkt->srcID;
        DestID = pkt->destID;
        Pver = pkt->pver ;
        Profiles = pkt->profiles;
        Length = pkt->length;
        Data = pkt->data;
        printf("Data Received from Client_1 are :\n");
        printf("Source ID: %ld\n", SrcID);
        printf("Destination ID: %ld\n", DestID);
        printf("profile Version: %d\n", Pver);
        printf("No of Profiles: %d\n", Profiles);
        printf("Length: %d\n", Length);
        printf("data : %ld\n", Data);
    }
    if (rc == 0)
    {
        printf("Connection closed by Server\n");
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n",received_bytes);
    }

    if (rc == -1)
    {
        perror("recv");
    }
    {
        if (close(newsockfd) == -1) {
            error("Error closing connection with client 1");
        }

        printf("Connection with client 1 has been closed\n");
    }
    return 0; 

}
```

The output that I see on the client's console is:

```
Client Side:  Client 1 trying to connect with server host 130.191.166.230 on port 1234
SUCCESS !!! Connection established 
Started Creating packet
packet send done
```

and on the server's console I see:

```
Server Side:  Data Received from Client_1 are :
Source ID: 1
Destination ID: 2
profile Version: 0
No of Profiles: 1074462536
Length: 0
data : 0
Connection closed by Server
Bytes received: 8
Connection with client 1 has been closed
```

Comment: Please look at how the code got formatted - the indentation is totally unreadable.

Comment: I answered one like this just yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791022

Comment: because the number of bytes you are sending is 8 bytes.  This line `send(sockfd,pkt,sizeof(packet_size),0)`  is equivalent to `send(sockfd,pkt, 8, 0);`

Comment: what is the meaning of this line `pkt->data = 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8;`

Comment: but i defined packet_size as long double...which is 16 bytes right??

Comment: i want numbers 1,2,3, inside tha data field of packet.

Comment: @Nikolai: I read your reply for somewhat similar question, so what you suggest, that I should buffer the received data or send in some other fashion.I am confused as where exactly i am wrong...while sending or receiving

Comment: the size of long double depends on the platform. It could be 8, 10, 12, or 16 (as far as I know). This is why we told you to worry about serialization.  Anyhow, declare packet_size as `int` and then assign a value for `packet size = sizeof(struct packet)` in both the client and the server. BUT remember this code will run only on the same type of machines.

Comment: @badawi: Yes, that has solved the problem. Now in my data field I want to send numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,.......these can be random and max can be 1000. Right now I just see Number "1" at the o/p. How to achieve this?? any idea??

Comment: @badawi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1770/discussion-between-user537670-and-badawi)

Comment: It looks like the OP needs to read a basic C programming book about the syntax of the language and how to assign to fields in a struct.  This hash nothing to do with socket programming really.

Comment: @Chris Dodd: I am amateur with C programming.....can you guide how to proceed, it would be of great help....thanks

Comment: A simple search http://www.google.com/search?q=learn+C or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=learn+C will give you lots of pointers...

Comment: @user537670 use a debugger to locate the problem and read the documentation of the library (`man` pages in your case) you intend to use. You should not ask others to fix your code for you. You should know what you are doing before attempting to accomplish it. Avoid posting long snippets of code and just post the part you don't understand after you have done enough research on your part. This types of questions clutter the stackoverflow and wastes other's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

```
recv(newsockfd,pkt,sizeof(packet_size),0)) /* What is packet_size ? */
recv(newsockfd,pkt,sizeof(struct packet),0)) /* You probably mean this. */
```

That might solve your problems, but there are a few issues with the way you are using TCP sockets.

> But at my client side, it prints that it has sent everything

Where ? I don't see you actually checking the number of bytes sent. `send(2)` can return after sending less that you asked it to.

> It shows me that only 8 bytes were sent by Client and prints them out.

TCP is a stream-oriented protocol. You send bytes and they arrive, in the same order. So when you `recv(2)` something, you might get less (or more than you wrote). So, the following can be true:

```
client:
send 100 bytes
send 400 bytes

server:
recv 50 bytes
recv 150 bytes
recv 250 bytes
recv 50 bytes
```

The number of `send` and `recv` calls need not be identical when using `TCP`.

Comment: so you mean to say,client might be sending all the bytes but my recv is recving only a few, so how can i gurantee that sending and receiving is proper....

Comment: Refresh the page and see my answer (what is `packet_size`?). You can keep receiving until you get the entire `packet`.

Comment: packet_size is defined as "long double".

Comment: @user537670 `struct packet` is bigger than that

Comment: thanks, now it shows that it received 24 bytes...One more thing in the data field of my packet i want to send the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,......this can be random and max limit of numbers is 500. Here it shows that it just received number "1". How to achieve this??

Comment: just a small note for the example: if the client sent 100 bytes (first send) that will fit in one segment and you can read the whole thing on the server side.

Comment: @yi_H: so you mean to say it is not able to send the entire data??

Comment: @user537670: that was for the answerer. it looks like you have prodigious amounts of questions, you should read Steven's networking bibles (TCP Illustrated vol1, UNIX Network programming).

Comment: @yi_H: I am on it...will look for that book....But any idea @ my question how to send different numbers in the data field and server receiving it??The data field of my packet i want to send the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,......this can be random and max limit of numbers is 500. Here it shows that it just received number "1". How to achieve this??

Comment: There are dozens of problems with your code, solving that one problem won't help you. You need to allocate memory (or use a large enough pre-allocated array), fill it with the numbers, for efficiency send with writev so it's one call, then fix the receiver side to handle partial "packets" and so on... this is not a horse race, first try to understand the subject then write the code. then, if you don't understand *one* thing, feel free to ask.

Comment: @yi_H Yes, it does fit in a segment. But the receiver is free to split it whichever way it likes (although in most cases it will just `recv 100`).

Answer (score 2):

When you call `send` the function returns the number of bytes actually sent and this number can be less than the number of bytes you wanted to send. So every time you want to send something there must be a loop like the following

```
bool sendBuffer(SOCKET s, unsigned char *buf, int size)
{
    while (size > 0)
    {
        int sz = send(s, buf, size,0);
        if (sz < 0) return false; // Failure
        size -= sz; // Decrement number of bytes to send
        buf += sz;  // Advance read pointer
    }
    return true; // All buffer has been sent
}
```

and a similar loop must be done when receiving (in other words `recv` can return less bytes than what you are asking for).

If you don't make these loops the risk is that everything **apparently** will work anyway (until the size of an ethernet packet) when you work on your local machine or even over a LAN, but things will not work when working across the internet.

Note also that as other answers pointed out you asked to send `sizeof(packet_size)` i.e. the number of bytes required to store that variable, not the size of the structure.

Comment: Are you sure your function should return `bool*`?

Comment: @6502: thanks,One more thing in the data field of my packet i want to send the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,......this can be random and max limit of numbers is 500. Here it shows that it just received number "1". How to achieve this?? Is it because I am not to doing the loop thing that you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

There is an informal rule that nobody is allowed to write any software that uses TCP until they memorize this sentence and can fully explain what it means: "TCP is a byte-stream protocol that does not preserve application message boundaries."

What that means is that TCP only ensures that you get out the same bytes you put in and in the same order. It does not "glue" the bytes together in any way.

Before you write any code that uses TCP, you should either use a protocol that is already designed (such as IMAP or HTTP) or design one yourself. If you design one yourself, you should write out a protocol specification. It should specifically define what a protocol-level message will consist of at the byte level. It should specifically state how the receiver finds the ends of messages, and so on.

This may seem a little silly for simple applications, but trust me, it will pay off massively. Otherwise, it's almost impossible to figure out why things aren't work because if the server and client don't quite get along, there's no arbiter to say what's right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't specialise in socket programming but there are a few things I've noticed. As far as I'm aware, I don't think you can send structs over sockets that easily. You may wish to consider a different method.

NB, when using send/recv you're also determing the sizeof packet_size, and not the sizeof the struct.

Googling brought up this about sending structs over sockets: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=613906